# Find text between the first two same characters of my choice with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror

> Assume the following output

.

```
20198818-119903 | firmware-check | passed: host test-1000 is connected to a test with Version: 333 | |
20198818-119903 | other-test-123 | passed: host test-1000 is connected to a test with 333:
20198818-119903 | test4| passed :| host | is connected to a test with 333
20198818-119903 | something | passed: host test-1000 is connected to a test with Version:
```

> > I want to extract firmware-check, other-test-123, test4, and something

So basically **everything** between **the first two** vertical bars.

I tried to solve this problem with txt2re but didn't work how I wanted (eg doesn't ignore host on the third line). I have never worked with regex and don't want to learn it just for this particular case. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: [`^[^|]*\|([^|]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/ESS2zF/1) or [`^[^|]*\|\s*([^|]*?)\s*\|`](https://regex101.com/r/ESS2zF/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
^[^|]+\|([^|]+)
```

[image]

```js
let str = `20198818-119903 | firmware-check | passed: host test-1000 is connected to a test with Version: 333 | |
20198818-119903 | other-test-123 | passed: host test-1000 is connected to a test with 333:
20198818-119903 | test4| passed :| host | is connected to a test with 333
20198818-119903 | something | passed: host test-1000 is connected to a test with Version:`

let op = str.match(/^[^|]+\|([^|]+)/gm).map(m=> m.split('|')[1].trim())

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression would simply extract those values:

```
.*?\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|.*
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/HnQ1zd/1/)

```js
const regex = /.*?\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|.*/gm;
const str = `20198818-119903 | firmware-check | passed : host test-1000 is connected to a test with Version: 333 | |
20198818-119903 | other-test-123 | passed : host test-1000 is connected to a test with 333:
20198818-119903 | test4| passed :| host | is connected to a test with 333
20198818-119903 | something | passed : host test-1000 is connected to a test with Version:`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex `/[^|]+\|\s*([^|]+)\s*\|.*/` to get the first match between `|` into a capturing group. Use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and a while loop to get all the matches.

(You could also use [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to skip the while loop, but it is still in *Draft* status)

```js
let str = `20198818-119903 | firmware-check | passed : host test-1000 is connected to a test with Version: 333 | |
20198818-119903 | other-test-123 | passed : host test-1000 is connected to a test with 333:
20198818-119903 | test4| passed :| host | is connected to a test with 333
20198818-119903 | something | passed : host test-1000 is connected to a test with Version:`,
    regex = /[^|]+\|\s*([^|]+?)\s*\|.*/g,
    match,
    matches = [];

while(match = regex.exec(str))
  matches.push(match[1])

console.log(matches)

// OR
// matchAll is still in Draft status
console.log(
  Array.from(str.matchAll(regex)).map(a => a[1])
)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BvWSma/1)